# Skype crashes when selecting photo for avatar

Tags: skype

I have a problem with Skype. When I try to set an avatar, it crashes when I click on a photo, through the selector.

I'm running Skype 4.0.0.8 on 12.04. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

To install **Skype** the correct way:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: i installed skype from the official ubuntu repositories so that didnt work... still have the same bug